# Aligning two clouds using two manually selected points

Tags: point-cloud-library

I'm maintaining software which uses PCL. I'm myself not much experienced in PCL, I've only tried some examples and tried to understand the official [PCL-Ducumentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/group__common.html) (which is unfortunately mainly sparse, doxygen-generated text). My impression is, only a PCL contributors have real change to use the library efficiently.

One feature I have to fix in the software is aligning two clouds. The clouds are two objects, which should be stacked together with a layer in-between (The actual task is to calculate the volume of the layer ).

I hope the picture explains the task well. The objects are scanned both from the sides to be stacked (one from above and the other from below). On both clouds the user selects manually two points. Then, as I hope there should be a mean in PCL to align two clouds providing the two clouds and the coordinates of the points. The alignment is required only in X-Y Plane.

Unfortunately I can't find out which function should I use for this, partly because the PCL documentation is IHMO really humble, partly because of lack of experience.

My desperate idea was to stack the clouds using P1 as the origin of both and then rotate the second cloud manually using the calculated angle between P11,P21 and P12,P22. This works, but since the task appears to me very common, I'd expect PCL to provide a dedicated function for that.

Could you point me to a proper API-function, code-snippet, example, similar project or a good book helping to understand PCL API and usage?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem does not need PCL. It is simple enough to form the correct linear equation and solve it.

If you want to use PCL without worrying about the maths too much (though, if the above is a mystery to you, then studying some computational geometry would be very useful), here is my suggestion.

Most PCL operations work on 3D point clouds. I understand from your question that you only have 2D point clouds OR you don't care about the 3rd dimension. In this case if I were you I would represent the points as a 3D point cloud and set the z dimension to zero.

You will only need two point clouds with 3 points as that is how many points you are feeding to the transformation estimation algorithm. The first 2 points in the clouds will be the points chosen by the user. The third one will be any point that you have chosen that you know is the same in both clouds. You need this third one otherwise the transform is still ambiguous if it is a general transform that is being computed. You can calculate however such a point as you know 2 points already and you know that all the points are on a common plane (as you have projected them by losing the z values). Just don't choose it co-linear with the other two points. For example, halfway between the two points and 2cm in the perpendicular direction (ensuring to go in the correct direction).

Then you can use the estimateRigidTransformation functions to find the transform.
http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1registration_1_1_transformation_estimation_s_v_d.html

This function is also good for over-determined problems (it is the workhorse of the ICP algorithm in PCL) but as long as you have enough points to determine the transform it should work.

Comment: As I mentioned, I've got the code form some one else and assumed, the implementation used the best possible approach. Good to know, that it's not a harm not to use PCL when working with point clouds. My clouds are 3D, but XY-planes are parallel - so for alignmeng Z of both point-sets can be set to any equal value (e.g. 0). Many thanks for pointing at `TransformationEstimationSVD`-class. I was not aware of it. Googling for it resulted in a useful link: [link](http://www.pcl-users.org/Strange-results-in-registering-two-point-clouds-td3577339.html). Seems to be a solution. Thank you!